# may be approximate. see faq 3.11 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently, phpmyadmin show this message at the top of my Records in database.

The description of this message is:
"The number of records for InnoDB tables is not correct.
phpMyAdmin uses a quick method to get the row count, and this method only returns an approximate count in the case of InnoDB tables. See $cfg['MaxExactCount'] for a way to modify those results, but this could have a serious impact on performance."

I would like to know will it further affect my database data if I ignore it?
Or should I cleared my database and re-created those data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know will it further affect my database data if I ignore it?

it won't affect you if you ignore it.

> Or should I cleared my database and re-created those data?

there's no need to re-create the data, it won't get rid of the message.

---

all that message is telling you is that the numbers shown in the Rows column might not be exact. this isn't a problem with the data or the database, but just something phpMyAdmin does to speed up showing that page. counting all the rows takes a long time.